# What is Hazelcast HD Memory? - on/off heap?

Tags: hazelcast

I have read [this](https://blog.hazelcast.com/introduction-hazelcast-hd-memory/) official post on the Hazelcast High Density Memory.

Am I right in assuming that this HD memory still consumes memory from the JVM (in which the application is running and not creating another JVM in the server and using it solely for hz instance)?

And that the only difference in this native memory configuration is that, the memory is allocated off heap rather than the default on-heap memory allocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMS or Hazelcast high Density Memory Store allocates memory into the same process space as the Java heap. That means the process still owns all the memory but the Java heap is otherwise independent and the Hazelcast allocated space (off-heap / non-Java-heap) is not target to Garbage Collection. Values are serialized and the resulting bytestream is copied to the native memory and when reading it is copied back into the Java heap area and sent to the requestor.

Imagine HDMS as a fancy malloc implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

HDMS or High Density Memory Store is part of Hazelcast Enterprise HD offering. HDMS is a way for Java software to access multiple terabytes of memory per node without struggling with long and unpredictable garbage collection pauses. This memory store provides the benefits of "off-heap" memory using of many high-performance memory management techniques. HDMS solves problems related with garbage collection limitations so that applications can utilizes hardware memory more efficiently without the need of extra clusters. It is designed as a plug-gable memory manager which enables multiple memory stores for different data structures like IMap and JCache.